# Processing XML from non-standard DTD in C#

Tags: c#, xml, dtd

I literally just want to be able to traverse the contents of various XML files that I have been given but having a non-standard DTD means I am hitting some issues - one error being "Reference to undeclared entity 'reg'" and another saying it is unable to locate the .DTD file.

Is it possible to do this sort of thing for XML files when no DTD is available? I have no control over these files and cannot change them. I am looking to grab various amounts of them at a time, move through the contents as efficiently as possible, email out some notifications and thats it.

Sample of XML file below:

```
<!DOCTYPE Toro-Pub PUBLIC "-//Toro//DTD Toro Publication V1.0//EN//XML" "Toro-Pub.dtd">
<!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2011, v.4002-->
<?Pub UDT _nopagebreak _touchup KeepsKeep="yes" KeepsPrev="no" KeepsNext="no" KeepsBoundary="page"?>
<?Pub UDT template _font?>
<?Pub UDT _bookmark _target?>
<?Pub UDT _nocolumnbreak _touchup KeepsKeep="yes" KeepsPrev="no" KeepsNext="no" KeepsBoundary="column"?>
<?Pub UDT instructions _comment FontColor="red"?>
<?Pub EntList alpha bull copy rArr sect trade deg?>
<?Pub Inc?>
<Toro-Pub><PubMeta Brand="Toro" CE="Yes" ClientPubNo="" CopyrightYear="2013" FormNumber="3378-827" Lang="CS" LangParentForm="3378-826" LangParentID="72729" LangParentRev="A" PageSize="" PhoneNoCan="" PhoneNoMex="" PhoneNoUS="" ProductFamily="sample product name" PubID="72730" PublicationType="Operator Manual" RegistrationURL="www.website.com" Rev="A" ServiceURL="www.website.com"><?TranslationData DueDate="07/01/2013" InCarton(1-yes)="0" Author="Mr Smith" EngParent="https://lwww.website.com?vPubID=423&vPubNum=3378-826" ?></PubMeta><Pub-TBlock>
<Body-TB>
...
```

Many thanks.

UPDATE #1

I have tried the below code taken from the suggested comment:

```
Stream file = File.OpenRead("4d00fa60800e0a5d_3378-827.xml");

// The next line is the fix!!!
XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(file);
xmlTextReader.XmlResolver = null;  // Don't require file in system32\inetsrv

XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
//readerSettings.Schemas.Add(null, "");
readerSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
readerSettings.XmlResolver = null; // Doesn't help

//readerSettings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationEventHandle;
XmlReader myXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlTextReader, readerSettings);

XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDocument.XmlResolver = null; // Doesn't help
myXmlDocument.Load(myXmlReader); // Load doc, no .dtd required on local disk
```

However, I now get a new error of 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.' on the line 'myXmlDocument.Load(myXmlReader)'.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894317/ignore-doctype-dtd-but-dtd-file-must-still-exist ... that will let you ignore the DTD.

Comment: I tried the solution from the suggested link but I now get a new error of 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.' on the line 'myXmlDocument.Load(myXmlReader)'.

Comment: What is "non-standard" about Toro-Pub.dtd?